# show progressdialog when downloading bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, progress-bar

I want to show a progressbar downloading a bitmap:

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            progressDialog.setProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            Log.i("progre+ss", (int) (total * 100 / fileLength) + " ");
        }

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

which is initialised with:

```
    private void openprogresdialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PrMapGen.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Generating File...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.show();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                generatePrMap(DataArray,
                        getIntent().getExtras().getString("project"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            projdata.close();
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

My problem is the following:

when I use the while loop to update the progressbar, no image is returned, when I delete the while loop the bitmap is returned successfuly.

Why???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tip to do it the easy way.

Declare an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Put your code to download the image in the **doInBackgroud()** and set the progressBar inside **onUpdateProgress()**.

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) too.